# Creating custom application links (ed2k link style) in C#

Tags: c#, windows

I'd like to create a way to intercept "special links" to my application (myapp://myinfo, for instance) as apps like edonkey do.

First thing is to register then as described [here](http://wiki.amule.org/index.php/Ed2k_links_handling), for instance, so that the browser end up invoking something like "yourapp.exe link".

So, I have two questions:

- Is there a better way to create "custom links" than the one described above
- In order to prevent a new app instance to be launched per link, what's the best mechanism you would use? (I'm thinking on some sort of IPC, based on something as simple as finding other instances and if they're there, send it the command (using a socket, or a message, or whatever)). What's the most common method?

Thanks!!

Comment: Take a read of [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28VS.85%29.aspx) to understand registering your application to a custom protocol in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided on creating custom-links is very nice...

The second question... well, in my opinion, you could be making two apps:

- One light wight app is only used to redirect to the main app.
- An app that would be the main application. The main app receives messages sent from the first app.

I wouldn't use sockets, unless you want to make a download server the can handle download orders from multiple machines.

Answer (score 1):

First question: The linked approach is essentially the correct one. Just do it programmatically - don't launch a reg file.

Second question: Check out [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CSSIApp.aspx) of showing you how to detect multiple instances and notifying the first instance.